# Переделать строчку с Python 2.x на Python 3.x

Tags: python, циклы

Только начал, поэтому заранее прощу прощения, если вопрос кому-нибудь покажется глупым.

Есть код, написанный на 2м пайтоне (это я узнал из гугла):

```
for i in range(1, 10):
 for j in range(1, 10):
  print "%2i" % (i*j),
print
```

По идее, он выводит таблицу умножения. Опять покопавшись в гугле, я узнал, что контструкция `"%2i"` должна выводить целочисленные типы, состоящие из 2х символов (если я правильно понял), а также - что оператор print стал теперь функцией, соответственно, заключается в скобки.

```
for i in range (1,10):
    for j in range (1,10):
        print (i*j)
```

Так выводится таблица умножения в консоли. Но вопрос в том - как переделать строчку так

```
print "%2i" % (i*j)
```

чтобы на выходе получить то, что хотел получить создатель этих строк?

Comment: Редкий случай, когда ответ уже написан в самом вопросе - "_оператор print стал теперь функцией, соответственно, заключается в скобки_"

Answer (score 6):

Вызывайте `print` как функцию, а чтобы не было перевода на следующую строку, указывайте параметр `end=`, по умолчанию он равен `'\n'`:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        print("%2i" % (i * j), end=' ')
    print()
```

Консоль:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 
 3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 
 4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 
 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 
 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 
 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 
 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

---

**PS.**

Помимо `%`-форматирования, есть и другие варианты:

- `print("{:2}".format(i * j), end=' ')`
- `print(f"{i*j:2}", end=' ')`